# move c++ program to foreground

Tags: c++, linux

I used `daemon()` and `fork()` to move my program to the background.
How can I bring it back to the foreground?
Is there a c++ function that do so?
thank you.

edited:
I understand that there is no way back from `daemon()` so how can I move my program from foreground to background and back?

Comment: These "commands" are called "functions" actually.

Comment: You can wait for the fork to die naturally; http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait but this isn't exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

what daemon does is to close the standard io channels.  There is no way to 'reopen' them.  A standard practice is to arrange for some other IPC mechanism, such as a socket, and interact with the daemonized process with another program.

Answer (score 0):

There is no C++ command for this.  `fork()` and `daemon()` aren't C++ commands.  They are POSIX commands (it helps to keep the difference in mind).

You can increase how often your program is scheduled time on the CPU with the command line utility [`renice`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/renice.html), but that won't get you any windows or messages from the program.